# qTip2 - content from hidden div after few clicks dissapear

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I when I was playing with qTip2 great plugin for tooltips I approach on two problems:

After few (sometimes 4 or 7) clicks in first 'Click me!' link content of hidden div is missing. Another strange thing is that link inside second 'Click me!' link has own title, which is displayed by qTip2 :-)

If anyone have had this problems?

**The code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var arrayData = [],
        elems = $('div'),
        tips = $('a');

    tips.each(function(i) {
        arrayData.push(parseInt($(this).data('tooltip'),10)-1);

        $(this).qtip({
            show: 'click',
            hide: 'unfocus',
            content: {
                text: $(elems[arrayData[i]])
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

**Link to working example:**  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/kW669/9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer your questions in two parts.

1) The disappearing content
Actually this one puzzles me as well. If you inspect the DOM and click: 1st link, 4th link, 1st link. Then the div disappears. It seems like the 4th link "steals" the content from the first, when you click it. A solution to this would be to clone the content before handing it to the qTip2.0. If you want a better understanding of why this is happening. You should try to ask on the forum. The author of qTip normally answers most questions.

2) The title on the link is because you select every anchor tag (`<a>`) in the DOM and applies the qTip to all of them. This can be solved by adding classes to the ones you want to actually become qTips.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="tip" href="#" data-tooltip="1">Click me!</a>

<a class="tip" href="#" data-tooltip="2">Click me!</a>

<a class="tip" href="#" data-tooltip="3">Click me!</a>

<a class="tip" href="#" data-tooltip="1">Click me!</a>

<div class="hidden elem">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 1</div>
<div class="hidden elem">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 2 <a href="#" title="bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 2">link</a></div>
<div class="hidden elem">ccccccccccccccccc 3</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrayData = [],
        elems = $('.elem'),
        tips = $('.tip');

    tips.each(function (i) {
        arrayData.push(parseInt($(this).data('tooltip'), 10) - 1);
        var text = $(elems[arrayData[i]]).clone();

        $(this).qtip({
            show: 'click',
            hide: 'unfocus',
            content: {
                text: text
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And updated JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kri5t/9f81vh0e/

Comment: Thank You for explanation. Using .clone() helped. You have right with second answer - I forgot, that qTip plugin was initialized on all <a> elements :-)